white screen showning in IOS App with below Error
I'm working on a hybrid app called moodle, i have customized the app, done minor changes like fixing url, changing logo and other customization
The app is running fine on Android device both on physical and emulator
But while running app on Ios device im only getting a white screen everytime running the app with the below warning
Failed to request allowed query parameters from Webprivacy
The app is based on cordova, node, angular and typescript
For running the app we required below
Cordova installed
Ios platform
Node version
i have tried on
cordova : 12
Ios platform : 4.1.1 and 5.1.1
Node version : >14.15.0 to 15 (required by project )
And
cordova : 12
Ios platform : 7.1.1
Node version : 18.18.0 ( as required by package.json)[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/uSUUr.jpg)
I have provided required permissions
Tried following solutions
OnDeviceRrady - written correctly in index file
AutoHidesplashscreen - set to true in config.xml

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
